# Resizing Text/Shape/Anything With and Action in Photoshop CC 2018

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, batch-processing, actions

i am trying to create an action in Photoshop CC 2018 that will allow me to batch resize a piece of text to a specific spot on the canvas.

I have my PSD with all of my necessary layers in, i have then used variable data to spit out multiple PSD's with my desired text changes, i am now trying to make each piece of text (regardless of size) scale to the same position and size.

I am able to get the action to work on the document i am working on but as soon as i run the action across a batch of files it seems to completely ignore the transform x/y that i have specified. i have tried it with.

- The text box
- Converting to a smart object
- Converting to a shape

All produce the same effect, ultimately all i am wanting to do is say Here's a rectangle area, fit this layer to said area but, it seems like such a basic function that is missing from PS and i cant for the life of me figure it out, First time posting on stack exchange, sorry if the formatting of this article is poor,thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! For complex questions like this it is beneficial to add images to help others understand what you are working with. Additionally adding the action/file/required resources would help us see what you have set-up.

Comment: If I restate your problem as, looking for a quick keys, or repeatable action to place the same item on multiple documents at the exact same size? Does that sound right? I don't know of any individual function that will take your final size into account when working with variant sizes. The best guess on how to do it would be to set it up as a Shape under the Graphic & Web workspace. That way you'd be able to add it at exactly the right size on any document you are in. I have 'where' not 'how' though.